# How to create search functionality for website to filter results by date in JS

Tags: javascript, search

How would you go about creating search functionality on a website using JavaScript. To elaborate, I have a whole list of objects that are keyed on a date (it will be YYYY-MM-DD) and at the moment, the website retrieves all objects and lists them on the page, which obviously over time will look awful and take forever to load and render. So to mitigate this future issue, the objects will be divided by year then when clicked on it will filter per month, then per day but I want the user to be able to search for an explicit date if they know what they want and for the web page to only show the result that matches their search. I haven't got a clue where to start with search and the only examples i've found are exact string matches, but ideally i would want partial matches as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any code you might be willing to share re: any work you've already done?

Comment: I haven't implemented any code yet purely because I want to get the theory straight in my head before I try and write any code. The front end currently pulls all records in one big read from the DB so i have them in hand so the search wouldnt need to go back to the database at all which i think will make it quicker since it only has to search within the objects at hand?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overloading your server, you should look into designing database queries in your server that retrieve the amount of results you need, sorted by date, using parameters such as "current page" and "start/end date".

Client app would call for example:

```
http://example.com/search?page=2&startDate=05102019&endDate=20102019
```

So your frontend only receives the results it needs to display.

The "page" parameter is there to limit the amount of results given each time.

Comment: The front end currently pulls all records in one big read from the DB so i have them in hand so the search wouldn't need to go back to the database at all which i think will make it quicker since it only has to search within the objects at hand?

Comment: I would recommend the other approach. Not sure what your final target is, but in cases of websites for the public, if people are all requesting big reads it doesn't scale well, it may overload the server. Better practice is to make your server process specific searches, and let the frontend display the results. If all the data is on the client side already, you can use the array "filter" method to get the parts you need.